# Counting the total amount of iterations in loop

Tags: python

I've created a program which generates string iterations. However, I'm having trouble getting it to print the total number. Here is my code:
    from itertools import product
    for password in commonpasswords:
        password = password.strip('\n')

Essentially I'd just like 1 number with the total number of mutations. Thanks.

I'm also getting a KeyError '\r', if you could help me with that.

EDIT: This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    allPossible = list(product(*([letter] + mapping[letter] for letter in password)))
  File "test.py", line 17, in <genexpr>
    allPossible = list(product(*([letter] + mapping[letter] for letter in password)))
KeyError: '\r'
```

Comment: Your `commonpasswords.txt` file probably has `\r` as newline characters. Your `mapping[letter]` letter call throws that error because `\r` isn't in your `mapping` dict.

Comment: You're probably using Windows/DOS-style newlines (`\r\n`) and only stripping the `\n`s. That said, I thought that opening a file in text mode (which you are doing: `open('commonpasswords.txt', 'r')` automatically converted all line endings to `\n` anyway. I could be wrong, though...

Comment: `strip` the `\r`s also

Comment: So . . . The problem is the KeyError?

Comment: What do you not like about `len(allPossible)`?

Comment: l have 2 errors, one being the KeyError and the len(allpossible) isn't giving me 1 number, it keeps incrementing then whilst printing the number, then giving me the \r error.

Comment: I've tried changing the password variable to  password = password.strip('\n') and password.strip('\r') and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: You need to do both - stripping both potential forms of line endings.

Comment: Is my syntax correct? in the comment before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the `KeyError \r`, follow `password.strip('\n')` with `password.strip('\r')`

### What does the KeyError mean?

It means you're trying to look up a value in your `mapping` dictionary that doesn't exist

In this line

```
allPossible = list(product(*([letter] + mapping[letter] for letter in password)))
```

the `for letter in password` is going through the letters one by one and then looking up their possible replacements in `mapping` i.e. `mapping[letter]`.  As with any dictionary, if `letter` isn't a key in `mapping`, you'll get a KeyError.

You need to decide how to handle characters not in the dictionary.  You could do a few things

1. Put that line in a `try` block and then catch Errors using `except`.  This would omit that password from your results but allow your code to keep going
2. Keep stripping characters (as you have with `\n` and `\r`) until your sure you only have left characters in the map
3. Add mappings for all characters you might find into the dictionary (e.g. add `'_':['_']` as an entry to `mapping`)
4. Alter your statement finding mutations so that it only works on values in the `mapping` dictionary.

### Print out a single number at the end

With that fixed, your code outputs a running total number of mutations for the file - adding on the mutations for each line one by one

If you only want to print at the end (i.e. total for file)  remove the indentation from the `print(total)` line.

### Indentation

You might have misunderstood the python indentation structure - each indented line following a `for` or `while` will run once per loop.  You don't want the `print` statement to execute on each loop, so remove the indentation.

Comment: I've changed password.strip('\n') to password.strip('\r') and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Don't change it, add it afterwards.  Also - I'm guessing "still getting the error" is imprecise - I think it probably errors at the first loop now (i.e. no longer printing any numbers) and says `KeyError '\n'`

Comment: Ok I've added it afterwards now I'm getting this error:  KeyError: '_'

Comment: You need to be really precise. I'm going to update my answer with what the KeyError means.  You're now getting an error because '_' is not in your `mapping` dictionary, but must appear in one of your common passwords.  You need to change your code to cope with these cases and handle errors. I'll suggest how in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Breaking your code into functions can make it much easier to understand and re-use
2. You can use `dict.get` to provide a default value for items not in the dictionary;

   ```
   v = count.get(ch, 1)
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
   try:
       v = count[ch]
   except KeyError:
       v = 1
   ```
3. You can calculate the number of variants by multiplying the number of alternatives for each letter; this is *much* faster than actually generating all the possibilities and counting them.
4. You can use `word.strip()` instead of `word.strip("\n").strip("\r")`; it removes any leading or trailing tab or space characters, but this is irrelevant because they have no mappings and therefore do not affect the final total.

So,

```
mapping = {
    'a': ['A', '@'],    'b': ['B', '8'],    'c': ['C', '('],
    'd': ['D'],         'e': ['E', '3'],    'f': ['F'],
    'g': ['G'],         'h': ['H'],         'i': ['I', '1'],
    'j': ['J'],         'k': ['K'],         'l': ['L'], 
    'm': ['M'],         'n': ['N'],         'o': ['O', '0'],
    'p': ['P'],         'q': ['Q'],         'r': ['R'], 
    's': ['S'],         't': ['T', '7'],    'u': ['U'], 
    'v': ['V'],         'w': ['W'],         'x': ['X'], 
    'y': ['Y'],         'z': ['Z'],         '1': ['i', 'I'],
    '2': ['2'],         '3': ['e', 'E'],    '4': ['H', 'h'], 
    '5': ['s', 'S'],    '6': ['b'],         '7': ['L', 'l'], 
    '8': ['B'],         '9': ['9'],         '0': ['o', '0']
}

# precalculate number of variants for each letter
count = {ch:len(lst)+1 for ch,lst in mapping.items()}

def variants(word):
    """
    Return the number of variations possible
      by replacing some letters in `word` with
      their alternatives from `mapping`
    """
    p = 1
    for ch in word:
        p *= count.get(ch, 1)
    return p

def total_variants(wordlist):
    return sum(variants(word) for word in wordlist)

def main():
    with open("commonpasswords.txt") as inf:
        print(total_variants(line.strip() for line in inf))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```